# How to select the element that has exactly the specified text

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm not able to find anchor element by it's exact text content

**HTML**

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);">Project One</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0);">Project</a>
```

**JS**

```
var vInput = "Project";
alert($("a:contains('" + vInput + "')").length);
```

**Output**

```
2
```

I want the output to be `1`. Is there any way that I can match only the anchor element with the text `Project` NOT `Project One`?

Comment: `alert($(".a").filter(function (){ return $(this).text()==vInput}).length)`

Comment: I'd do it with other selector 'var anchor = $(a[

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `filter()` function and check if the text matches the desired string:

```js
alert($('a').filter(function() { 
  return $(this).text() == 'Project';
}).length);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="javascript:void(0);">Project One</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0);">Project</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [.filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter) for matching the exact content as [:contains()](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) will return partial matches

```js
var vInput = "Project";
var $as = $('a').filter(function() {
  return vInput == $(this).text().trim()
})
alert($as.length);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="javascript:void(0);">Project One</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0);">Project</a>
```

Comment: I would remove `trim` . code should not has decision of it's own

Answer (score 0):

USe `filter`

```
var vInput = "Project";
var anchors = $("a").filter(function() {
    return $(this).text().trim() == vInput;
});
alert(anchors.length);
```